# put Ruby configuration into non-ruby configs

Tags: ruby, configuration, format

I'd like to be able to have configuration (with the ability to code in Ruby) in one place. Since different configs (like bash scripts) don't understand Ruby, I'd have to prepopulate them. Is there an easy-to-use tool for this?
I've found [ruby-parseconfig](https://github.com/derks/ruby-parseconfig) but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can do this with [chef templates](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Templates).

Example:

```
#
# /etc/sudoers
#
# Generated by Chef for <%= node[:fqdn] %>
#

Defaults        !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn

# User privilege specification
root          ALL=(ALL) ALL

<% @sudoers_users.each do |user| -%>
<%= user %>   ALL=(ALL) <%= "NOPASSWD:" if @passwordless %>ALL
<% end -%>
```